# jQuery crashing

Tags: php, jquery

Good day **StackOverflow**'ers

Today my code is just crashing. It's almost impossible to publish the code here so I let you the link to my site http://www.wetwindweb.com/. Please help me!

I'm sorry but imagine to paste all the code! And **please, don't vote down**. I let you the json code here because it doesn't shows always.

```
{
    "phrases": [
        {
            "id": "182",
            "text": "saassa",
            "date": "2012-03-17 17:32:51",
            "views": "0",
            "ip": "200.77.116.205",
            "reported": "0",
            "strange": "0",
            "lang": "en"
        },
        {
            "id": "181",
            "text": "s",
            "date": "2012-03-17 17:22:33",
            "views": "0",
            "ip": "200.77.116.205",
            "reported": "0",
            "strange": "0",
            "lang": "en"
        },
        {
            "id": "180",
            "text": "ssxsas.com'\r\n",
            "date": "2012-03-17 17:22:06",
            "views": "0",
            "ip": "200.77.116.205",
            "reported": "0",
            "strange": "0",
            "lang": "en"
        },
        {
            "id": "179",
            "text": "sadsad",
            "date": "2012-03-17 17:21:41",
            "views": "0",
            "ip": "200.77.116.205",
            "reported": "0",
            "strange": "0",
            "lang": "en"
        },
        {
            "id": "178",
            "text": "?©??ß ƒ?''",
            "date": "2012-03-17 17:21:04",
            "views": "0",
            "ip": "200.77.116.205",
            "reported": "0",
            "strange": "0",
            "lang": "en"
        },
        {
            "id": "177",
            "text": "|@#¢?¬÷“”?´œœæ€®†¥  ø?'''",
            "date": "2012-03-17 17:20:27",
            "views": "0",
            "ip": "200.77.116.205",
            "reported": "0",
            "strange": "0",
            "lang": "en"
        },
        {
            "id": "176",
            "text": "sdsdds",
            "date": "2012-03-17 10:41:14",
            "views": "0",
            "ip": "200.77.116.205",
            "reported": "0",
            "strange": "0",
            "lang": "en"
        },
        {
            "id": "175",
            "text": "Here\\'s a new quote",
            "date": "2012-03-17 09:55:04",
            "views": "0",
            "ip": "200.77.116.205",
            "reported": "0",
            "strange": "0",
            "lang": "en"
        },
        {
            "id": "174",
            "text": "This is the phrase number 99",
            "date": "2012-03-15 15:45:00",
            "views": "0",
            "ip": "64.191.90.5",
            "reported": "0",
            "strange": "0",
            "lang": "en"
        },
        {
            "id": "173",
            "text": "This is the phrase number 98",
            "date": "2012-03-15 15:45:00",
            "views": "0",
            "ip": "64.191.90.5",
            "reported": "0",
            "strange": "0",
            "lang": "en"
        }
    ],
    "details": {
        "success": "true",
        "total_count": "145",
        "phrase_text": "",
        "phrase_date": "",
        "last_fetched": "17:40:10"
    }
}
```

With crashing I means it freezes the code, just after posting a phrase. 
You can use it and try to get the errors

Thanks!

**UPDATE** Corrected the hostname :P

Comment: How do you define "crashing"? What are the precise symptoms? Also, the hostname you've posted doesn't resolve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you try to call $.parseJSON on the response which isn't JSON at all, but the whole html page.

The debugger states clearly:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
>   in ui.js line 97